# Can I change the size of a clipboard element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

What should happen:

Copy an image, as normal. When you press a button - the image is placed inside a div (it becomes a different size when it is made the background). When the div is clicked, it writes the image back onto the clipboard, able to be pasted (assuming you copied something else in the meantime), at the same dimensions as the oringal.

What's actually happening:

The new pasted image/clipboard sets it's own dimensions, despite being given the dimensions it should adhere to.

The Code:

```
export async function run() {
// Try to access clipboard data using the Clipboard API
const images = await navigator.clipboard.read();
const image = images[0];

if (image.types[0] === "image/png" || image.types[0] === "image/jpg") {
// Load the image using the ImageBitmap API to get its dimensions
const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(await image.getType("image/png"));
const width = bitmap.width;
const height = bitmap.height;

// Now you have access to the width and height of the image
console.log("Image width:", width);
console.log("Image height:", height);

insertImage(image, width, height);
}
}

//THIS WORKS BUT WRONG SIZE//
async function insertImage(clipboardItem, height, width) {
 clipboardItem.getType("image/png").then(async (blob) => {
 if (blob) {
  const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   const hereDiv = document.querySelector(".here");
  hereDiv.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imageUrl}')`;
  hereDiv.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
  hereDiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  hereDiv.style.backgroundPosition = "center";

  // Attach the click event listener to the div after the image is inserted
  hereDiv.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    // Read the background image directly from the div and copy it to the clipboard
    const backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(hereDiv).backgroundImage;
    if (backgroundImage && backgroundImage !== "none") {
      const imageUrl = backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['"]/g, "");
      fetch(imageUrl)
        .then((response) => response.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({ "image/png": blob }, { "image/png": blob });
          clipboardItem.imageWidth = width;
          clipboardItem.imageHeight = height;

          console.log(clipboardItem);

          navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem]);
          const images = navigator.clipboard.read();
          console.log(images);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error copying image to clipboard:", error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("No image available to copy.");
    }
    });
  }
  });
  }
```